# Cassandra QueryBuilder Selection Issue with Static Variable

Tags: java, cassandra

I have found an issue with the cassandra-driver-core library that results in a NoHostAvailableException.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
    <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you have a static variable that holds the columns as such:

```
private static final Select.SelectionOrAlias allSelection = QueryBuilder.select().
            column("id").
            column("version_id");
```

It seems like there is an issue when you resuse the static variable using a query builder, e.g.

```
Select s = allSelection.from(TABLE);
s.where(QueryBuilder.eq("id", id)).
                and(QueryBuilder.eq("version_id", version.getVersionId()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library will continuously add the last column in the selection, version_id, to the allSelection variable which will eventually result with a massive column selection query that will timeout to the Cassandra node and if you are running a cluster it will eventually take all your nodes out of the pool of available servers and any query will be rejected due to a NoHostAvailable exception.

Possible Solutions:

1. Generate the column variable every time you use it
2. Just do a select * or QueryBuilder.select()
3. Use prepared statements (recommended for performance reasons)

*Note: This was happening for me with version 3.0.0 and 3.1.0 of the cassandra-driver-core library. Not sure about other versions.*